# How to set a column in qwidgettable as accounting format in python?

Tags: python, datatable, format, pyqt5, qwidget

I have a `qwidgettable` that i want to set the specific column(i call it "Amount" column) to be in accounting format that if i type Eg. `1000` turns to `1,000.00` after I leave that cell and go over to another cell. I looked over the net but I couldn't find specific response to this query. Thank you so much in advance.

I actually tried this code but I don't know how to finish this:

```
self.table_data.setItemDelegateForColumn()
```

Edit:

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt Tuts')
        self.table()


    def table(self):

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 100, 411, 392))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.show()

        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText("Amount")
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)

        attr = ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4', 'Product5']
        i = 0
        for j in attr:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(j))
            i += 1

def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

What I want to achieve is when I put 1000 in the amount in product 1. This will automatically become 1,000.00 after i leave that cell.

Not like this:

[image]

But like this: (this is just a snasphot in excel-format):

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Nick. I have edited my question for clarity. Hope you can respond to this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> QStyledItemDelegate Class
>
> The QStyledItemDelegate class provides display and editing facilities for data items from a model.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class InitialDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, decimals, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.nDecimals = decimals

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        try:
            text = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            number = float(text)
            option.text = "{:,.{}f}".format(number, self.nDecimals)
        except:
            pass


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt Tuts')
        self.table()

    def table(self):
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 100, 411, 392))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)

        delegateFloat = InitialDelegate(2, self.tableWidget)              # <---
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegateFloat)       # <---
        
        self.tableWidget.show()

        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText("Amount")
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)

        attr = ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4', 'Product5']
        i = 0
        for j in attr:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(j))
            i += 1


def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Nick! This is exactly what I need. Glad that I brought this up here. One thing I just want to add is the alignment. How to align it in currency format? like align in the middleright? I tried changing it in alignright. ''' option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight'''  but by default it seems to effect in topright  alignment. Thank you.

Comment: @AlvinLorejas  `option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter`. If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Yes that's what I need. Thank you so much for the help Nick!